# <identifier> expected. java

Tags: java

I have this snippet of java code. I am a noob in java..

Error :

```
<identifier> expected
cfg = new Config;
```

Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.io.*; 

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Config 
{

   Properties configFile;
  public Config()
{
configFile = new java.util.Properties();
try {           
  configFile.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config"));          
}catch(Exception eta){
    eta.printStackTrace();
}
  }

  public String getProperty(String key)
  {
 String value = this.configFile.getProperty(key);       
    return value;
  }

}



public class ClosureBuilder {
```

`cfg = new Config();`

```
private static String JDBC = cfg.getProperty("JDBC");
private static String URL = cfg.getProperty("URL");
private static String DIMENSION_TABLE = cfg.getProperty("DIMENSION_TABLE");
private static String CLOSURE_TABLE = cfg.getProperty("CLOSURE_TABLE");
private static String KEY = cfg.getProperty("KEY");
private static String PARENT_KEY = cfg.getProperty("PARENT_KEY");

private static Object TOP_LEVEL_PARENT_KEY = '0';


private Object topLevel = null;

private Set<Object> processedNodes;

private PreparedStatement aPst;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

----------- More code --------
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is the problem:

```
public class ClosureBuilder {
    cfg = new Config();
    ...
}
```

At the top level of a class, you can only have:

- Instance initializer blocks (`{ ... }`)
- Static initializer blocks (`static { ... }`)
- Variable declarations
- Constructor declarations
- Method declarations
- Nested type declarations
- Finalizer declarations

This is none of these. If you *meant* to declare a variable, you should have done so:

```
private Config cfg = new Config();
```

If that's *not* what you intended to do, you should explain your intention.

EDIT: Once you've fixed that, this compiler error seems pretty clear:

> class Config is public, should be declared in a file named Config.java

There are two potential fixes for this:

- Make `Config` non-public
- Move it to a file called `Config.java`

Either should fix that error (potentially revealing more).

Comment: Error: class Config is public, should be declared in a file named Config.java

Comment: @cloudYturtle: So did you try following the pretty-clear instructions in the compiler error?

Answer (score 3):

Where are you declaring your `cfg` variable?

I only see the assignment. I think that may be the reason.

```
Config cfg = new Config();
```

Shoud fix it.

Comment: Already tried that .. :( Error : class Config is public, should be declared in a file named Config.java

Comment: @cloudYturtle: That just means there's *more than one problem* with your code. The compiler error tells you exactly what to do here - move your Config class into a source file called Config.java.

Answer (score 1):

Though your intention is not very clear, i assume  you want to have the cfg created before any other variable.
First declare your class Config as non-public or move to file Config.java.
It makes sense to initialize cfg in a static block. Below is a possible code snippet:

private static Config cfg = null;

private static String JDBC = null;

static {

```
  cfg = new Config();

  JDBC = cfg.getProperty("JDBC");
```

}