# Java: Instantiated object variable error

Tags: java

i have a problem that i'm afraid is very simple, yet i can't figure it out even with the help of lectures and tutorials.

I have this piece of code to create a class with some variables:

```
public class Symbol
{
    public String sign;
    public boolean win;
}
```

I then want to instantiate the class as an object and set its variables to a certain value like this:

```
Symbol x = new Symbol();
x.sign = "Rock";
x.win = true;
```

I did this exactly like the lecture i took said, but still i get the following error:

`"<identifier> expected"`

What am i doing wrong? There was no identifier declared in any example i looked at.
I am breaking my head over this for several hours now and - as embarresing as that is - i am at my wits end. Please help.

On a side note: I am using BlueJ to compile and run the code - if that is of any relevance.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show a complete example of the problem?  The entire class being compiled?  Which specific line shows the error?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686729/identifier-expected-java

Comment: post your entire code.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were all right.

The problem was, infact, with BlueJ.

When I ran the code with another editor it worked as intended.
I guess I know what I take away from this one ...

Still, thanks for all your answers.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "*You were all right*"? I can't refer which "you" whose solved your problem. Also, it'd be better if you could clarify the question by posting the full-but-short code, since it's kind of weird that some IDEs could run the code, but some couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon:

```
x.sign = "Rock"
```

Should be

```
x.sign = "Rock";
```

EDIT:

If that's a typo, then your code works fine.

Comment: you're right, but that was only a typo in the post.
I fixed it.
Very quick answering tho, respect

Answer (score 0):

I think you have written initialization code outside main method (directly in class)

```
public class Symbol
{
    public String sign;
    public boolean win;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Symbol x = new Symbol();
        x.sign = "Rock";
        x.win = true;
    }
}
```

Copy in main method.