# <identifier> expected error with address book comparator

Tags: java, linked-list, comparator

What seems to be the issue here?

```
public class ABook {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      LinkedList addressBook = new LinkedList(); //creates linked list
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int n = 1; //this will be used for the loop to act as a counter for the loop
      do {
        System.out.println("Would you like to add a friend? (Say Y or N)");
        String reply = input.nextLine();
        if (reply.equals("Y")) {
          System.out.println("What is the name of your friend?");
          String name = input.nextLine();
          System.out.println("What is the age of your friend?");
          int age = input.nextInt();
          Friend newFriend = new Friend(name, age);
          addressBook.add("Name: " + newFriend.name + "; " + "Age: " + newFriend.age);
          Comparator < CustomObject > comparator = new Comparator < CustomObject > () {
            public int compare(CustomObject c1, CustomObject c2) {
              return c2.getAge() - c1.getAge(); // use your logic
            }
            Collections.sort(addressBook, comparator);
            System.out.println("This is your Address Book so far: " + addressBook);
            n++;
          }
        }
    ...
}
```

The compiler is complaining here:

```
Collections.sort(addressBook, comparator);
```

with the  `<identifier> expected` error.

If you can find a solution, could you explain how or why your solution works, as well as what is the comparator.

Comment: Not relating to your problem, but you **seriously** need to format this code. Nothing hurts developer's eyes more than a wall of code like this!

Comment: possible duplicate of [<identifier> expected. java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686729/identifier-expected-java)

Answer (score 1):

The call to `Collections.sort` is outside the method `compare` but inside the definition of your anonymous inner class.

Move the call to `Collections.sort` after you have finished your anonymous class and the declaration of the `comparator` variable.

You'll also need to add a semicolon after the `}` that ends the anonymous class declaration.